# Order by in LINQ method syntax

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-order-by

I have tried inserting an orderby into this query in every conceivable spot, but can't get it to work. In this linq query, I am pulling a list of unitMixes related to a single property. There is a field called createDate in the unitMixes table that I would like to order the results by, this seems simple but I just can't quite get my mid around method syntax yet.

```
var viewModel = new propertyDetailData();
viewModel.properties = db.properties.Where(s => s.propertyId == id).Single();
viewModel.unitMixes = db.properties.Where(s => s.propertyId == id).Single().unitMixes;
```

Thanks in advance,
john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewModel.properties = db.properties.Single(s => s.propertyId == id);
viewModel.unitMixes = db.properties.Single(s => s.propertyId == id).unitMixes
                                       .OrderBy(m => m.createDate)
                                       .ToList();
```

You can do the orderby on the list.
You don't need to get the list and then do `.Single()` you can search the `Single()` element that `equals` your `delegate`

Answer (score 0):

```
viewModel.unitMixes = db.properties.Where(s => s.propertyId == id)
                                   .Single().unitMixes
                                   .OrderBy(m => m.createDate)
                                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewModel.properties = db.properties.Where(s => s.propertyId == id).Single();
viewModel.unitMixes = viewModel.properties.unitMixes.OrderBy(u => u.createDate);
```